# application for uk visa after 10 years ban expires

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

is there any one that has applied to the uk embassy after given the 10 years ban and the ban expires? I want to know what the chances are. Thanks

Comment: Your chances depend on your unique circumstances. But you'll need to do a very good job to convince the UK that you won't do again whatever got you banned last time. You probably ought to hire a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for your response. would you advise I get a lawyer in my home country or from the UK?

Comment: I'm not an expert but I believe the usual advice is a UK lawyer specializing in immigration issues. [The Law Society](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/) is, I think, the place to look.

Comment: The UK regulates and registers those who legally may give immigration advice, and a lawyer outside of the UK is not in the best position to guide you. Take a look at [this answer for links to the services you might need](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115526). A competent attorney in the UK wouldl not accept a case, or money, if it is unlikely to succeed.